# Secure Connection Failed SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE when Certificate shows as active in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-certificate-manager

I have a custom domain name set up in Namecheap which is used for an S3 bucket hosting a static site via Cloudfront.  I created a certificate in AWS Certificate manager to use.

When I try to access the site, it tells me that the cert is revoked:
[image]

The cert that the browser is receiving shows that it's active.
[image]

It matches the following cert in AWS which also shows as active:
[image]

I also queried the cert and noticed that 4 were returned:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect beta.mywebsite.ca:443 -showcerts
```

So what gives?  It's serving me an active, issued cert but it says that it's revoked.

Comment: Not programming or development, but: **revocation != expiration.** The dates you show establish the cert isn't expired, but that doesn't mean it isn't revoked. OpenSSL `s_client` doesn't check for revocation -- and doesn 't fail even if a cert IS expired or invalid. The additional certs you see with `s_client -showcerts` are the higher levels in the cert chain, which are irrelevant to the revocation status of your end-entity cert. ...

Comment: ... OTOH ACM shouldn't revoke your cert without at least informing you, and would reflect any revocation in 'Status' -- and when I ask the Amazon responder specified in your (not-fully-redacted) cert it says 'good'. I wonder if it's possible your browser is using a defective OCSP responder, although this would have to be explicitly trusted to override the signed-by-CA requirement, and would be a quite weird thing to do, except maybe for some unit-test or debugging situations. In any case even if this were ontopic I doubt we can resolve it remotely.